# Split a line/sentence in two in C#

Tags: c#

How can I split different part of a sentence in a text file and put each part where I want?

I have this in a text file:

Marc;260.65
Sonia;450.37
Richard;195.00
Bob;50.00
Paul;789.00

I want to read the file using StreamReader and append the result to be something like this:

Marc, Amount: 260.65 $ 
Sonia, Amount : 450.37 $ 
...

Here's my code so far:

```
StreamReader File1 = new StreamReader("test.txt");
            string sSentence = "";
            string sAmount = "";

            while (!File1.EndOfStream)
            {
                sSentence = File1.ReadLine();
                sSentence.Split(';');
                txtResult.AppendText(sSentence + ",sAmount : "+ sAmount + " $"+"\n"); 
            }
```

Basically I don't know how to associate the number with the variable sAmount to append it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use Replace()?

```
sSentence.Replace(";", ", Amount: ");
```

Comment: Also, this needs to go inside `AppendText`